# Not enough memory error with Microsoft Word

Tags: windows-8, memory, microsoft-word, memory-error

Friend's computer (Dell, running Windows 8 64-bit) has been getting a weird error recently; whenever he tries to open a Microsoft Word file from Windows Explorer his computer tells him that there is

> Not enough memory to run Microsoft Word

(The title bar on the pop-up claims that the message comes from "Microsoft Word 14.0," which I suppose is possible.....)

Some trial and error revealed that, oddly enough, opening a file from the `File >> Open` dialog (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) is not an issue; additionally, files may be opened from Explorer when Microsoft Word is already open.

What gives?

Comment: I'd do a malware/virus check. If Windows is opening up something else first before opening Word (as the file association is hijacked) this would cause a similar problem.

Comment: @cathoo Good idea.....I suggested that to him, and he told me that he doesn't have an antivirus installed; he doesn't have the time.....

Comment: @AnotherUser your friend has time to ask you a question, but doesn't have time to install antivirus? Sounds very selfish. Anyway, we use malware bytes for scanning malware... give it a try: https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/

Comment: @sunk818 Agreed. Thanks for the recommendation!